# Make it easier?

Tags: c

When I read [the article](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html) which is a simple note for C programming,
one question was raised in my mind.

Can I make following code easier to read?
I tried several things but still it was not cool.

```
if(goleft)
     p->left=p->right->left;
else
     p->right=p->left->right;
```

Code is simple.
p is a pointer to a node.
Node is whatever you can think.

Can you show me a good answer?

Comment: So not `( goleft ? p->left : p->right) = ( goleft ? p->right->left : p->left->right );`? :)

Comment: @James: the conditional operator, in `C`, does not return "lvalues".

Comment: @pmg: Well it should.  How else am I supposed to write nigh unreadable code for simple operations?  That just leaves tremendous amounts of pointer indirection. :(

Comment: LOL, C is unfair: compiler implementors have it easy :)

Comment: @popopome What is this code intended to do? That's how to make code readable: by stating such things. And whatever that is, this code is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @Jim The code might be wrong or not. But you know the code is written by "Rob Pike". ^^

Comment: @jim-balter - I think the logic of the code is beside the point in the article. I think the point behind it is to demonstrate how pointer notation makes a complex expression more concise and easier to read because of its compactness vs. the alternative array notation used as the contrast.

Comment: The question was about making the code easier to read. The one vital thing required to make this code readable is to add a comment stating what it does. If you don't understand that, you don't understand the concept of code readability.

Comment: @popopome It doesn't matter who the code was written by (although if Rob Pike wrote it, it's not at all surprising that it's wrong). What does matter is that you didn't answer my question, here and below, and have made no attempt to clarify anything. Again, the way to make the code readable is to add a comment stating what it does -- that's what a competent programmer would do.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell out of context, but calling a pointer `p` isn't very descriptive. `node` or `np` may be better.

(This code isn't that simple, btw; while reading it, the first thing that came to my mind was "isn't that a memory leak?")

Comment: That kinds of code are in all over C books and C code examples. How about this: "p" is a node in double linked list? <br> Can we make any more improvement without just changing variable name? I tried to abstract the pointer assignment code with good name, but it was hard.

Comment: @popopome: I use `p` for pointers as well some times, but mainly for `void *`. Again, this is hard to answer without context. The code is short and sweet, but we don't know if it does what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the need for making the code more readable you can always go the objective way:

```
if (goleft)
  move_left(p);
else
  move_right(p);
```

Comment: This is C, so it should be either `p = move_left(p)` or `move_left(&p)`.

Comment: @larsman: `p` is a pointer (the `->` says so), passing the pointer to functions and changing what it points to is ok.

Comment: @pmg: My mistake, only members of the structure pointed to are changed. Sorry, Let_Me_Be!

Comment: +1 I agree; and this is generally the best solution for these sorts of questions.

Comment: What, please, is moving? If you're going to give things names, give them the right ones. If this is a binary tree, then a node is being disconnected from it and then leaked. The OP has asked how to make the code more readable, but oddly comments play little role in the answers being provided here.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have `left` and `right` as two explicit fields, it's hard. However, if you instead would have an array with length two, say `directions`, you could write something like:

```
  int dir = (goLeft ? 1 : 0);

  p->directions[dir] = p->directions[1 - dir]->directions[dir];
```

Comment: There are reasons to do such things when you have completely symmetric operations and that depend on a parameter, but you cannot possibly think that this is more readable ... which was the question. And if you're doing things this way, you shouldn't mix up directions with bools ... there should only be dir, not goLeft.

Comment: Also you have some dependent parameter (dir) that you just created. The point in the article link, I think, is to use pointers such that you make your intentions clear using pointers and object fields/members and without needing to introduce any other state information.

Comment: @Jim: No, I do not consider it more readable. I just wanted to point out the limitations of having fixed "left" and "right" fields.

Answer (score 1):

A little whitespace goes a long way:

```
if(goleft)
{      
  p->left = p->right->left; 
}
else
{
  p->right = p->left->right;
}
```

Right now about 20 people are screaming about using `{}` for single statements.  Let 'em scream.  It gives the code some vertical breathing space, which makes it a little easier for these aging eyes to read, *and* it guards against the inevitable runtime bugs that arise when someone wants to add a statement to the else case (such as the one that bit me not two days ago).

That's pretty much as readable as the code is going to get (and, as readability goes, it's not that bad, at least for C).  It's simple, it's explicit, anybody picking it up knows exactly what's happening.  Trying to hide it behind function calls or macros for the sake of making it "prettier" is more work than it's really worth IMO.

Comment: If you think that is readable, then please tell us what it does. The point of things like move_left/move_right is documentation and encapsulation. However, in this case those are definitely the _wrong_ names, as nothing is "moving" here, a data structure is being altered ... without a hint of what alteration is being performed.

Comment: The OP didn't provide enough (heck, *any*) context to make that determination.  It's "readable" in the sense that I can tell it's setting one or the other child to point to the corresponding node of the opposite child.  Whether that's the right thing to do or makes any sense is impossible to determine without knowing why he's doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this actually helps in this case, but the first thing that came to my mind was something like this:

```
if (goleft)
{
   npp = &(p->left);
   kid = p->right->left;
}
else
{
   npp = &(p->right);
   kid = p->left->right;
}
*npp = kid;
```

but I really don't think that that helps at all

Answer (score 0):

```
// a comment saying what this does
if( goleft ) p->left = p->right->left; 
else         p->right = p->left->right;
```

I don't know what the comment should be because this code doesn't make any sense to me; it appears to disconnect `p` from its left or right successor and instead points it to itself, assuming that `p->right->left` and `p->left->right` are sensibly `p` itself. And the test doesn't make sense because you aren't "going" anywhere, you're modifying the list. What would make sense is

```
Node* next = goleft? p->left : p->right;
```

My comment here is based on yours that this is a doubly-linked list. If instead it is a binary tree then the code makes a bit more sense, but then you're removing a node but not saving a link to it. As larsmans mentioned, this looks like a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

Some white space and a little commenting goes a long way

```
if (goleft)
     /* skip the immediate left turn and use the next one instead */
     p->left = p->right->left;
else
     /* skip right turn */
     p->right = p->left->right;
```

Comment: I think refactoring is better than commenting. Especially for such a simple piece of code.

Comment: Agree with the whitespace, but the comments don't add anything, IMHO.

Comment: It would be great if I can understand the code without comment.

Comment: Ok, I overdid the comments. Hopefully, in the real code, it would be obvious what `goleft`, `p`, `right`, and `left` mean.

Comment: But what isn't obvious is what the operations `p->left = p->right->left` and `p->right = p->left->right` do. They do not move, they do not skip ... they _alter_ a data structure. The alteration appears to be a bug, and a comment describing what the code is _intended_ to do would go a long way toward identifying the bug.